# How to add a different search filter in windows explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

See picture below, there is an option saying that I should be able to `add a search filter` but it got gray out, does anyone knows how to enable it or how to add a different search filter?

Windows 7 sp1 x64

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives you the two options for search filter in that directory: `Date modified:` and `Size:`.  You simply select one of them to get more filter options.

And before you say it, yes I agree this is not very intuitive user interface design.

[image]

Comment: lol, I know there are 2 available options, My question is `how to add a different filter`

Comment: I think you misunderstand... "Add a search filter" is not an `option` -- it is a `label`.  The list of options beyond that label are what you can pick, which are the two filters available.

Comment: So there is no more filter I can add there...

Comment: @RootLoop Correct

Comment: But I know there are more options for indexing.

Comment: Different directories give you different options.  For example, in your Pictures library you will get the additional "Date taken:" and "Tags:" options.

Comment: @RootLoop: "So there is no more filter I can add there" - Yes you can. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The UI for in-built search since Windows 7 onwards is truly unintuitive and atrocious and a major step backwards since XP, but it does support [Advanced Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows you to use a whole lot of different keywords, Boolean operators and other assorted file properties (you can't add your own however unless you're a programmer). Basically just ignore the two options shown and type the filter based on whatever's available as per that article.

It doesn't make sense to replicate the MSDN article here in its entirety, so I suggest you peruse it at your leisure. However if you want my recommendation there are far superior third-party file indexing and search utilities available that will allow better use of your time.